# Web service advice for an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, web-services

I am currently working on an iPhone app that will have a user log in, enter a workorder or building, and the app will display workorder/building information. The user will then be able to edit some of the data and submit it to the server. The backend database is a MySQL server. What is the best web service to use for this situation? I've been reading about SOAP, JSON, etc. but I honestly haven't found a good description of the pros/cons of each and how well they work with an iPhone app. Any and all help (or links to useful reading) would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby On Rails or PHP is your best bet for the web services layer that goes between the phone and the MySQL and go for JSON as that is the most commonly IPhone Web service data format as it is the one that requires the least amount of data upload by the phone. Touch JSON is commonly used IPhone framework for this.The RoR or PHP web services layer serves up JSON data based on URL requests by the IPhone. There's loads of stuff on this if you google which I did when faced with a similar problem.

Comment: I'll definitely take a deeper look into JSON. I had looked at so many different options that I honestly just needed some second opinions because one site will tell you "X is best" and another will say "Y is best". I trust the opinions of people on this site much more than I trust some blogger. (Especially when I can explain my exact situation). Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Ruby On Rails or PHP is your best bet for the web services layer" -> that is non-sense. Any RESTful web service should work. It just needs to respond to smthg u expect and handle (JSON, XML, (x)html). Just pick a modern web framework, you r familiar with or — at least — know it language. That can be RoR, Django, Dupral,..., or even very exotic like Bombax (objective-c). I use cocoahttpserver to access data on iPhone.

Comment: He's just looking at a starting point and no one was answering his question. I made a decision to go with RoR when faced with this exact same problem so it's what I know.